# sending canvas img in ajax

Tags: javascript, cordova

```
    var theImage= $(".login_input_camera").prop("files")[0];
```

theImage is an input type="file"
know the ajax is working
but i wont to change theImage to a url and then to send him in ajax to my server
its not working Because TheImage need to be object file

can i convert "img src" to object file?

```
        var theImage= $.theText;
```

alert($.theText)
        fdata.append('json',JSON.stringify(vdata));
        fdata.append('image1',theImage);

```
    $.ajax({
        url:'http://192.211.50.206/users/signUp?userName=' + vUserName + '&uniqueDeviceId=' + device.uuid +'',
        data: fdata,
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        type:'POST',
        success: function (data)
                {
                    alert("success")
                    alert(data)
                    //$(".loading").hide();
                },
            error: function (ts) 
            {
                alert("notGood")
                alert(ts.responseText);
                allError(ts.responseText)
                $(".loading").hide();
            }
        });
```

Comment: So, whats the problem? Is there an error? Please specify exactly what information you are looking for.

Comment: the problem is that i try to send url like an object file